# Is there a way to verify a username.github.io subdomain (not custom domain) with Google developer console?

Tags: google-workspace, google

I've been trying to register a hobby app project at [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com). While registering the OAuth consent screen, I'm told that I must supply a domain verified with Google:

[image: google oauth screen]

Now, since this is a hobby project, I don't want to register a new custom domain but use my github pages subdomain which is [prahladyeri.github.io](https://prahladyeri.github.io/) instead. However, I see no way to [verify this subdomain at Google search console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) as it asks for updation of a TXT/CNAME record for verification. I'd like to ask experts, is there any way to verify a `username.github.io` subdomain with Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **HTML tag** to verify your site provided you can add some meta contents to your site. They would give you some html like `<meta ....>`

Click on **try a URL prefix property**. Then click on the **URL prefix** tab. Here, you have to enter your **URL with https** and press **Continue**. You will be given the options to add **meta tags** for your site verification.

Comment: Thanks, the URL prefix method worked for me!

Comment: I am glad it worked 